# LINQ/Entity Framework exception - Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

If I try to run a simple LINQ query `DbContext.Tenants.ToList()` on the table, I get `Invalid column name 'PartnerId'` exception. I do not have `PartnerId` in the Tenant table or entity class. Could you help me know the reason for the exception?

```cs
        public IList<Tenant> GetAsync()
        {
            return DbContext.Tenants
                .ToList();
        }
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tenants](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [FullName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IsGlobal] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ModifiedOn] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Enable] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Tenants] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

```cs
    public class BasicEntity<TKey>
    {
        public TKey Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public bool Enable { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
    public class Tenant: BasicEntity<Guid>
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsGlobal { get; set; }
        public List<Environment> Environments { get; set; }
        public List<TenantCompanies> Companies { get; set; }
        public List<TenantMeta> TenantMetas { get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
    public interface IAdminTenantManagementSystemDbContext
    {
        DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        DbSet<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
        DbSet<Entities.Environment> Environments { get; set; }
        DbSet<Partner> Partners { get; set; }
        DbSet<PartnerTenants> PartnerTenants { get; set; }
        DbSet<TenantCompanies> TenantCompanies { get; set; }
        DbSet<TenantMeta> TenantMetas { get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
    public class Partner : BasicEntity<Guid>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<PartnerTenants> PartnerTenants { get; set; }
        public List<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
        public List<Environment> Environments { get; set; }
        public List<TenantCompanies> Companies { get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
    public class PartnerTenants
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
        public Guid PartnerId { get; set; }
        public bool Enable { get; set; }
        public Partner Partner { get; set; }
        public Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'PartnerId'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.EntityFramework.Repositories.TenantRepository`1.GetAsync() in D:\data\code\tms\Get.Caa\IdentityServer.Admin\src\Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.EntityFramework\Repositories\TenantRepository.cs:line 32
   at Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.BusinessLogic.Services.TenantService.GetTenantsAsync() in D:\data\code\tms\Get.Caa\IdentityServer.Admin\src\Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.BusinessLogic\Services\TenantService.cs:line 71
   at Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.Api.Controllers.TenantController.Get() in D:\data\code\tms\Get.Caa\IdentityServer.Admin\src\Skoruba.IdentityServer4.Admin.Api\Controllers\TenantController.cs:line 42
   at lambda_method42(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|26_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ExceptionContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Do you have any Entity mapping class? Where do you define the DB constrains on the app side? Share that part of the code?

Comment: Not enough information to resolve this issue, you context, for the tenet table->object, would be nice.

Comment: @Rahatur, what do I look for  Entity mapping class in my project? What do I need to search for?

Comment: @MortenBork, I have added DbContext interface IAdminTenantManagementSystemDbContext. Is this what you were asking for?

Comment: @SyedRafeyHusain Look for `.Property` or `.IsRequired()` or `.HasMaxLength` in your code base. those are the most commonly used keywords.

Comment: You've given the definition of `Tenant` twice and omitted the definition of `Environment`, `TenantCompanies` and `TenantMeta`. But really, you're faster off searching for `PartnerId` in your entire source -- EF is not the one inventing that column.

Comment: @Rahatur, I have hundreds of b.Property<int>("Id") but all of them are in Migrations folder which I believe runs during migration and not during `DbContext.Tenants.ToList()`.

Comment: Can you show the generated `SQL` log output, after performing the query

Comment: @WBuck, I have generated the SQL script in question from current database

Comment: @WBuck, How would I generate SQL log output, after performing the query?

Comment: Use `EnableSensitiveDataLogging` within the `Startup` `class` (this is done where you're configuring EF). After running the query you'll see the generated SQL dumped in the console.

Comment: Can you also show the definition of your `PartnerTenants` and `Partner` entities.

Comment: No what I meant is that the is a ORM context, in entityframeworkcore, the "DbContext" Type, defined somewhere in your code, if you did DB-first, then you named it when you did the scaffolding, and that is what you need to find the entity model mapping in that context, for the table "tenant" so we can see if that mapping has a partnerid in it, for example.

Try to do a "Search" in your entire solution, that contain the string "<Tenent>"
or "<Tenents>"

Comment: @WBuck, I have added `PartnerTenants` and `Partner` entities in question

Comment: @MortenBork, we are doing CodeFirst approach to build the database. I have added the structure of `Tenant` table in question.

Comment: @WBuck, we are enhancing IdentityServer4 from this repo https://github.com/identityserver/IdentityServer4 . I have seen Startup but I do not see EntityFramework initialization code to use `EnableSensitiveDataLogging`

Comment: @SyedRafeyHusain chenk your `PartnerTenants` table in your database. it's missing there.